# Maven unable to find java.lang

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, sdkman

I'm using `Java 8 Azul ZuluFX` on Lubuntu 18.0.4. I run on a project:

```sh
mvn clean package
```

but I get this error (simplified):

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] [parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/marco/sources/tgtools.activiti.explorer/src/main/java/tgtools/activiti/explorer/config/Constants.java]]
[ERROR] [parsing completed 13ms]
[many others...]
[ERROR] [search path for class files: /home/marco/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.212-zulu/jre/lib/rt.jar;[many others...]
[ERROR] Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

I checked and `/home/marco/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.212-zulu/jre/lib/rt.jar` exists, and it obviously contains `java/lang` folders, and its classes inside.

I have `Maven` 3.6.0